Nodal domain theorem for clamped plate equation
Let $\lambda_k$ and $\varphi_k$ be the $k$-th eigenvalue and a corresponding eigenfunction of the clamped plate equation in a bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$, $N \geq 2$.
That is, $\lambda_k$ and $\varphi_k$ satisfy
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
(-\Delta)^{2} \varphi_k &= \lambda_k \varphi_k &&\text{in}~ \Omega,\\
\varphi_k&=0 ,\frac{\partial}{\partial n}\varphi_k=0 &&\text{in}~ \partial \Omega.
\end{aligned}
\right. $$
The Courant nodal domain theorem provides a bound on the number of maximum nodal domains of $\varphi_k$ in the case of the Laplacian operator. My question is:

Does this theorem hold true for this equation as well? If not, what is the reason behind its failure?

The second question is also along the same line

Does there exist any version of Weyl's law for this kind of equation? Also, for the eigenvalue problem of Laplacian, i.e., if $\Delta f_k=\lambda_kf_k$, one could lift the function $f_k$ to a harmonic function by adding a variable. Can one lift the eigenfunction $\varphi_k$ in this case also to a Biharmonic function similar to the case of Laplacian?

Any suggestion/reference/comment will be very beneficial.

Is your boundary condition incomplete? By "clamped plate" do you mean that also the gradient of $\varphi_k$ should vanish on the boundary?

Yes sorry, I have edited it.

For some domains - for instance, the ball - the leading eigenfunction of the clamped plate equation can be chosen to be positive and thus has only one nodal domain. For many other domains - for instance for ellipses with large eccentricity - the leading eigenfunction does not have a sign and hence, there are at least two nodal domains. This is essentially due to the fact that there is no maximum principle for fourth order elliptic operators. There are a lot of papers on the topic by Guido Sweers, Hans-Christoph Grunau, and Anna Dall'Acqua, among others.

I see. Can you please mention the paper title if possible, I will try to have a look at these. Also any comment regarding the second question? Lifting and Weyl's law

Concerning the first question, as mentioned in the comments, it is known that the fundamental mode can have nontrivial nodal lines, which is different from the second-order case where we have a maximum principle. See: G. Sweers
"When is the first eigenfunction for the clamped plate equation of fixed sign?" (2001) Zbl 0963.35049 and many more papers by the same author. As far as I am aware, there isn't any analogue or generalization to Courant's theorem known so far. As a side remark, the nodal lines of the plate have been studied since the work of Chladni around 200 years back who excited elastic plates covered by sand with the bow of his violin, thereby making the nodal lines visible as nice pattern.
Second question: The asymptotics were studied in: A. Pleijel, "On the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of elastic plates" (1950, Zbl 0040.05403).

Thanks for the answer. Any comment or refernence regarding the lifting technique ?

Could you specify what you exactly mean by lifting technique?

Sure, by lifting technique, I mean for eigenfunction  $\phi_k$ of laplacian, if one considers the function $v=e^{-\lambda t}\phi_k$ then this lift is a solution of harmonic function in $\mathbb{R}^n\times (0,\infty)$.  I am asking whether the same kind of lifting technique is possible for bi-Laplacian case?
